# Are there any Open datasets for Human Resources?

Tags: data-request, economics, labor, companies

Are there any Open datasets/Taxonomies/… for Human Resources ? They would probably have to be anonymized. On any of the following topics

- Assessments/Background Checks
- Benefits Enrollment
- Recruiting
- Salary
- Timecard
- Interviewing
- Assessments
- Employee Benefits
- Onboarding
- Payroll
- Performance Management
- Screening
- Stock Plans
- Time Management
- …

Comment: You can download some of the topics from this list form the [World bank](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244106/getting-data-from-world-bank-in-topics-like-economics-human-rights-or-environme/244107#244107)

Answer (score 6):

Lots of data from the US Federal "Office of Personnel Management" (OPM).

**https://www.opm.gov/data/**

> OPM is the focal point for providing statistical information about the Federal civilian workforce. OPM's FedScope is an online tool which allows customers to access and analyze the most popular data elements from OPM's Enterprise Human Resources Integration (EHRI) Data Warehouse. Customers include Federal government agencies, researchers, the media, and the general public. OPM provides numerous Raw Datasets (including FedScope data) for customer's use.

https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/data-analysis-documentation/

I think in SAS format (which can be converted to be used in R or Python or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

I've been compiling datasets related to HR for a while now, and store them on my [GitHub](https://github.com/teuschb/hr_data/tree/master/datasets) repository, not always with all the attribution I should.

Another dataset is at [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/ludobenistant/hr-analytics), and [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/communities/analytics/watson-analytics-blog/hr-employee-attrition/) hosts a popular dataset on employee attrition.

All these datasets are contrived, fictional, simulated, etc. because HR data is sensitive.

Comment: are these datasets hosted on your GitHub account open source?

Comment: Yes, they were all released as open source. Again, none of them are real data, but are all synthetic.